# Inconsistent back navigation

Tags: android

I have two Activities in my app (from AndroidManifest):

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="cyberdynesoftware.jahresurlaubapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

When I navigate to the SettingsActivity, there appears an arrow next to the App's name in the topbar. I haven't done any topbar/actionbar customizations. With that arrow I can navigate back to the MainActivity.

The MainActivity has an associated ViewModel that holds data to be displayed by fragments of the MainActivity. When I navigate back to MainActivity with the arrow mentioned above the ViewModel gets recreated and everything properly initialized with any changes I may have made in SettingsActivity.

However, when I navigate back to MainActivity from the SettingsActivity using the Android back button at the bottom, the data in the ViewModel is not recreated. Instead, it seems that an old instance of MainActivity and its ViewModel still lurking around in memory is reused. Changes that I have made in SettingsActivity are not reflected.

**Question 1:** Why is the behaviour of back navigation inconsistent? Is there a use case where the two different behaviours are actually desired?

I think I have found a way to fix this (in SettingsActivity):

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    getOnBackPressedDispatcher().addCallback(this, new OnBackPressedCallback(true) {
        @Override
        public void handleOnBackPressed() {
            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

With that, the MainActivity and its ViewModel get recreated upon back navigation and all changes made in SettingsActivity are reflected.

**Question 2:** Is this a sound solution? Thus, does this force the behaviour I desire? Or does this just happen to do what I want on my device, but the behaviour may be different on other devices?

**Question 3:** Maybe I'm looking at all this wrong. Maybe I'm too focused on doing things a certain way. Is there a proper Android way to do this avoiding the problem I'm facing?

Comment: Remove the `<meta-data>` element from your second `<activity>` and see if that changes the behavior of your top bar up affordance (the arrow). "Is this a sound solution?" -- no. `MainActivity` is not properly observing changes to the data that `SettingsActivity` is changing.

Comment: "Remove the `<meta-data>` element" - I did not witness any change. I want to point out that this one actually behaves the way I want.

Comment: "MainActivity is not properly observing changes to the data" - that is true. MainActivity isn't observing anything. If I could rely on MainActivity and its ViewModel being properly initialized (thus, not an old instance reused) every time I navigate to it, that would be ok. Is this something I should never rely on? I guess, we're getting into architecture here. Any tips on that?

Comment: "Is this something I should never rely on?" -- correct. "I did not witness any change" -- hmmm... without the rest of your code, I'm uncertain how the up affordance is knowing where to go, let alone why it is recreating your activity unnecessarily. "I want to point out that this one actually behaves the way I want" -- just because the UX is what you want does not mean that the implementation is what you want.

Comment: "Any tips on that?" -- the docs have [a relatively extensive section on architecture](https://developer.android.com/topic/architecture/intro). I also get into architecture topics in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/) and [this free book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore/).